# Is there something like a minute Method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to know if there is something like 
    Time.now.hour 
for minutes? I really wondered as Time.now.minutes didn't work

Thanks for answers!

Comment: It would be useful for you to find tools that give more feedback. For instance, if you know where to look for the [docs](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/Time:min) then it's really easy to find. That's Ruby, there's also [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) for Rails. But, learning to jump into the console `$ rails console` is a great way to play around in your environment, and tools like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) make this a many many times richer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time.now.min` is what you are looking for I think.